# Shortest Partial Path in a Graph

Tags: node.js, algorithm, matrix, graph

I have a network that is defined by a matrix, where [i,j] element in the matrix is the cost of getting from node i to node j. If there is no path between i and j then [i,j] is Infinite.

I fill up the matrix with the negative values, so that if the distance between i and j is short then I put very small value in [i,j], for example -50, if the distance is long I put bigger value, for example -5.

I wonder how it's possible to find partial shortest path in network, the only constrains is the path should go in the predefined order, just like elements occur in matrix i,i+1,i+2,..

for simplified example,

```
╔═══╦═══╦═════╦═══╦═══╦═════╗
║   ║ 1 ║  2  ║ 3 ║ 4 ║  5  ║
╠═══╬═══╬═════╬═══╬═══╬═════╣
║ 1 ║ 0 ║ -20 ║   ║   ║ -10 ║
║ 2 ║   ║   0 ║   ║   ║     ║
║ 3 ║   ║     ║ 0 ║   ║     ║
║ 4 ║   ║     ║   ║ 0 ║ -50 ║
║ 5 ║   ║     ║   ║   ║     ║
╚═══╩═══╩═════╩═══╩═══╩═════╝
```

Here, the complete path form 1-to-5 equals -10, but if we take path 1-to-2 and then 4-to-5 we get better score -50, so here we skipped 3 and it's ok for partial path.

So the partial path - is a path that doesn't have to visit every node, it might be just short segment 1-to-2, bu the shortest partial path has to the shortest among all partial paths.

The constraint about the order is very simple, we always start searching path from node 1 and go in ascending order, so for all segments [i,j] [i1,j1] in the paths, j>i and i1>=j.

I wonder if there is a good way to find best score partial path in the network,  I think exhaustive search is also good solution, the number of nodes is around 15-20.

Comment: So, you can move from node `i` to node `j` only if `i<j`?

Comment: Also, define what you mean by 'partial shortest path'

Comment: I think I am still missing something, won't the shortest path in this case be just `(u,v)`, for using the edge with the lowest weight?

Comment: @amit, yep but the weight are negative, so we tend to aggregate as much segments as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) here, and you are looking for a longest path in it, according to `w(u,v)` - where `w(u,v)` is the *positive* weight of each connection (edge). If there is no edge between `u` to `v` we'll denote it's weight with negative infinity: `w(u,v)=-infinity`.

The graph is `G=(V,E)` where `V` is a *set* containing all your nodes, and `E = { (u,v,w(u,v) | u<v}` is the edges set.

In general, [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-Complete. Fortunately, your problem is a DAG, and there is an efficient [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solution to it. First [topologically sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the nodes, and then - from last to first:

```
d(v) = max { d(u) + w(v,u) | for all edges (v,u) }
```

When you are done, for each node `v` d(v) will denote the longest path that starts with this node, you will only have to find the maximal value out of these to get the desired node and maximal value.

You can reconstruct the path later on by:

```
v <- startNode //the node just found to be starting the desired path
list <- [v]
while (d(v) != 0):
   for each edge (v,u):
        if d(v) - w(v,u) == d(u):
             list.append(u)
             break
return list
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, I will try to implement it, however it looks like it doesn't consider the case of skipping the node.

Comment: I think this solution works but the answer is phrased oddly and it makes it seem like it works "by accident". I think you'd keep the edge weights _negative_ and it even works if there are positive weights. If there are missing edges, add "fake" ones with weight 0. Then when reconstructing the "partial path" just delete any edges with weight 0 (notice that if the edge happened to be "real" you don't care if it's removed since you'd still have a "partial path"). Also there isn't a need for topologically sorting--they're already ordered. Just construct the DP table from right to left